# iphone - problem with background image of uitextview

Tags: iphone, image, uitextview

I'm trying to add a back ground image to UITextView. The image is just a small border which will be placed at the top of text view. (the image resembles teared paper image). I'm using following code

```
  UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 13)];
  imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"teared_paper.png"];
  [tView addSubview: imgView];
  [tView sendSubviewToBack: imgView];   
  [imgView release];
```

My text view's height is 150 pixels only. (text view occupies only small portion of view and it is at the top of the view so that it will appear to the user when keyboard is there)

The problem is that, when I add more lines of text, text view is scrolling automatically. And at the same time, the background image that I added is also scrolling. How can I prevent the background image to stay on the top all the time irrespective of scrolling.

Comment: you can do that but you have to note that when you will scroll the TextView - your background also will be scrolled. So batter way is to put imageView behind the textView and set [textView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add the image view as a subview of the text view. Instead, have both the image view and the text view as children of the main view, position the image view behind the text view, and set the background color of the text view to transparent with:

```
[tView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Comment: you've got to be kidding. Is this the only way to achieve this? That;s so shocking!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try putting a UIImageView behind the UITextView and making the UITextView transparent?

Answer (score 1):

Try it with:

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 13)];
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"teared_paper.png"];
[tView addSubview: imgView];
[imgView release];
```

**Just make textView transparent :**

```
[textView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

no need to bring the subview to front.

Hope this works for u..